# Changing Joomla tables engine to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, joomla, transactions, innodb, myisam

I wrote an application in JAVA that adds articles to a Joomla site.
My problem is that inserting an article needs five queries to run (adding article to `content` table, inserting corresponding node to `assets` table , updating other nodes in `assets` table & setting asset id for inserted article); and because of that my JAVA application is running on a remote machine lots of problems can make any of these queries fail & if any of them fail the entire `assets` table breaks.
I thought about using transactions and manual commit to solve this but Joomla's Storage Engine (MyISAM) doesn't support transactions. so thought about converting storage engine of those two tables to "InnoDB".
Is this correct ?  doesn't it rise problems for Joomla(for example in JOINING with other tables that are using MyISAM)? 
Will it affect on site and makes it slower?
Is there any other solution (e.g. sending all 5 queries to server to run in sequence)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. I am not completely sure but I don't think Joomla should have any issues with InnoDB. When joining MyISAM and InnoDB tables in a JOIN, MySQL internally converts InnoDB to MyISAM. But I'm not a Joomla guy and I still can't be sure on it
2. Why not use triggers - an AFTER INSERT trigger on `content`?
3. You may also write a stored procedure for running all 5 INSERTs but again there will not be any transaction support
4. Create a single table to hold all data from all the 5 INSERT queries. Of course this table is only of an intermittent nature. Now create another stored procedure that will then migrate all data from this intermediate table to the respective tables.

Hope the above makes sense!

Comment: Hi, Thanks; Doesn't a trigger make problems with joomla's own queries? I mean when I create a AFTER INSERT trigger it runs on both my remote application queries (that should) and on joomla itself queries (that shouldn't!); can triggers configured to run only on my remote application queries?